# Kotlin NoSuchMethodError after installing a library that enables a plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I want to experience a library called [arrow analysis](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/meta/analysis/)

My `build.gradle.kts` file looks as follows:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:1.1.2")
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin:io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin.gradle.plugin:2.0")
    }
}

apply(plugin = "io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin")

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

after an attempt to build the project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtExpression org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.callUtil.CallUtilKt.getReceiverExpression(org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.model.ResolvedCall)'
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ast.kotlin.KotlinResolvedCall.getReceiverExpression(KotlinResolvedCall.kt:37)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ResolvedCallUtilsKt.allArgumentExpressions(ResolvedCallUtils.kt:75)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.ResolvedCallUtilsKt.arg(ResolvedCallUtils.kt:119)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.controlFlowAnyFunction(Expressions.kt:438)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.checkCallExpression(Expressions.kt:397)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.fallThrough(Expressions.kt:260)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt.access$fallThrough(Expressions.kt:1)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt$checkExpressionConstraints$2.invoke(Expressions.kt:244)
    at arrow.meta.plugins.analysis.phases.analysis.solver.check.ExpressionsKt$checkExpressionConstraints$2.invoke(Expressions.kt:157)
    at arrow.meta.continuations.ContSeq$flatMap$1.invokeSuspend(ContSeq.kt:60)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
```

I checked the source code, and everything seems to be in place. Did I something wrong as per the instructions to install this library which is denoted as follows:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath("io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin:io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin.gradle.plugin:2.0")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `apply` the plugin inside the `plugins` block and in the same fashion you're applying the Kotlin JVM plugin.

They mention to use it like [this on their official docs](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/analysis/)

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.21"
  // other plugins
  id("io.arrow-kt.analysis.kotlin") version "2.0.2"
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```